# Control volume of system sound

Tags: swift, audiotoolbox

I have the following code for playing a click when a button is tapped.

```
private var clickSound: SystemSoundID!

clickSound = createSound("ButtonClick2", soundType: "wav")

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(clickSound)
```

This sound plays at the same level, regardless of the volume on the device and whether the device is muted.

This is really two questions.

1. How can I detect whether the device is muted?  I want to not play the sound if the device is muted.
2. How can I adjust the volume of the sound based on the volume of the device?

Comment: `silentSound` you mean `clickSound `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this doesn't respond to user sound level is you created a system sound. Instead, use `AVAudioPlayer`.

```
do {
    let player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundFileURL)
    player.play()
} catch {
    print("Error")
}
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.

Comment: I've noticed one thing that's a bit of a problem.  The sound does play, for the most part.  It doesn't play for the first few button taps and sometimes if the buttons are being tapped quickly, the sound is skipped every so often.  If I play the click sound when first running the app, then it works better.  That's not really an ideal solution, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the  System Volume

```
let volume = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume   
print("Output volume: \(volume)"
```

the value of volume is from  0.0 to 1.0